# changing cursor icon while dragging the object JS

Tags: javascript, safari, cursor, drag

I have a problem in SAFARI with changing icon while dragging the object. It works in CHROME but does not work in SAFARI at all.
I was trying to change it using many drag events, changing the cursor for grabbing dynamically in JS and in CSS without the success. finally I was reading lots of articles where I found some ideas using dataTransfer without the result too. could you please provide me a quick and simple hint how to change the cursor icon for 'grabbing'? I was searching solutions in stack without the result. I was testing drag events, dataTransfer, without the result too. The icon remains unchanged.

Here is an example:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>

    <div class="box" draggable="true"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
.box{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: aqua;
    cursor: grab;
}
```

JS

```
const box = document.querySelector('.box');

box.addEventListener('dragstart',e => {
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', "I am dragging");
    box.style.cursor = 'grabbing';
})

box.addEventListener('dragend',() => {
    box.style.cursor = 'grab';
})
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: As you have requested I have added code snippets, have anyone idea how to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const draggableElement = document.getElementById("draggable");

draggableElement.addEventListener("dragstart", (e) => {
    e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", "This is draggable");
    // Change the cursor icon while dragging to 'grabbing'
    draggableElement.style.cursor = 'grabbing';
});

draggableElement.addEventListener("dragend", () => {
    // Reset the cursor icon after dragging ends
    draggableElement.style.cursor = 'grab';
});
```

```css
#draggable {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    cursor: grab;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Draggable Element</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="draggable" draggable="true">Drag me</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry, but this definitely does not work. It was already answered. I even copied 1 to 1 your snippet to codepen. does not work too. Any other ideas?